# How to remove checkbox icon in jqxtreeGrid only at parent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, controller

How to remove checkbox icon in jqxtreeGrid at only parent level not at children levels.

You can find a jsfiddle of my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Arvind_pal/LLASY/68/

For entries "Andrew" and "Steven" there should not appear a checkbox, see this screenshot:

[image]

**js file**

```
  var employees = [{
      "EmployeeID": 2,
          "FirstName": "Andrew",
          "LastName": "Fuller",
          "Country": "USA",
          "Title": "Vice President, Sales",
          "HireDate": "1992-08-14 00:00:00",
          "BirthDate": "1952-02-19 00:00:00",
          "City": "Tacoma",
          "Address": "908 W. Capital Way",
          "expanded": "true",
      children: [{
          "EmployeeID": 8,
              "FirstName": "Laura",
              "LastName": "Callahan",
              "Country": "USA",
              "Title": "Inside Sales Coordinator",
              "HireDate": "1994-03-05 00:00:00",
              "BirthDate": "1958-01-09 00:00:00",
              "City": "Seattle",
              "Address": "4726 - 11th Ave. N.E."
      }, {
          "EmployeeID": 1,
              "FirstName": "Nancy",
              "LastName": "Davolio",
              "Country": "USA",
              "Title": "Sales Representative",
              "HireDate": "1992-05-01 00:00:00",
              "BirthDate": "1948-12-08 00:00:00",
              "City": "Seattle",
              "Address": "507 - 20th Ave. E.Apt. 2A"
      }, {
          "EmployeeID": 3,
              "FirstName": "Janet",
              "LastName": "Leverling",
              "Country": "USA",
              "Title": "Sales Representative",
              "HireDate": "1992-04-01 00:00:00",
              "BirthDate": "1963-08-30 00:00:00",
              "City": "Kirkland",
              "Address": "722 Moss Bay Blvd."
      }, {
          "EmployeeID": 4,
              "FirstName": "Margaret",
              "LastName": "Peacock",
              "Country": "USA",
              "Title": "Sales Representative",
              "HireDate": "1993-05-03 00:00:00",
              "BirthDate": "1937-09-19 00:00:00",
              "City": "Redmond",
              "Address": "4110 Old Redmond Rd."
      }, {
          "EmployeeID": 5,
              "FirstName": "Steven",
              "LastName": "Buchanan",
              "Country": "UK",
              "Title": "Sales Manager",
              "HireDate": "1993-10-17 00:00:00",
              "BirthDate": "1955-03-04 00:00:00",
              "City": "London",
              "Address": "14 Garrett Hill",
              "expanded": "true",
          children: [{
              "EmployeeID": 6,
                  "FirstName": "Michael",
                  "LastName": "Suyama",
                  "Country": "UK",
                  "Title": "Sales Representative",
                  "HireDate": "1993-10-17 00:00:00",
                  "BirthDate": "1963-07-02 00:00:00",
                  "City": "London",
                  "Address": "Coventry House Miner Rd."
          }, {
              "EmployeeID": 7,
                  "FirstName": "Robert",
                  "LastName": "King",
                  "Country": "UK",
                  "Title": "Sales Representative",
                  "HireDate": "1994-01-02 00:00:00",
                  "BirthDate": "1960-05-29 00:00:00",
                  "City": "London",
                  "Address": "Edgeham Hollow Winchester Way"
          }, {
              "EmployeeID": 9,
                  "FirstName": "Anne",
                  "LastName": "Dodsworth",
                  "Country": "UK",
                  "Title": "Sales Representative",
                  "HireDate": "1994-11-15 00:00:00",
                  "BirthDate": "1966-01-27 00:00:00",
                  "City": "London",
                  "Address": "7 Houndstooth Rd."
          }]
      }]
  }];

  //// prepare the data
  var source = {
      dataType: "json",
      dataFields: [{
          name: 'EmployeeID',
          type: 'number'
      }, {
          name: 'FirstName',
          type: 'string'
      }, {
          name: 'LastName',
          type: 'string'
      }, {
          name: 'Country',
          type: 'string'
      }, {
          name: 'City',
          type: 'string'
      }, {
          name: 'Address',
          type: 'string'
      }, {
          name: 'Title',
          type: 'string'
      }, {
          name: 'HireDate',
          type: 'date'
      }, {
          name: 'children',
          type: 'array'
      }, {
          name: 'expanded',
          type: 'bool'
      }, {
          name: 'BirthDate',
          type: 'date'
      }],
      hierarchy: {
          root: 'children'
      },
      id: 'EmployeeID',
      localData: employees
  };
  var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

  // create Tree Grid
  $("#treeGrid").jqxTreeGrid({
      width: 680,
      source: dataAdapter,
      editable: true,
            checkboxes:true,
      hierarchicalCheckboxes:true,
      sortable: true,
      pageable: true,
      pagerMode: 'advanced',
      theme: 'energyblue',
      columns: [{
          text: 'FirstName',
          dataField: 'FirstName',
          width: 150
      }, {
          text: 'LastName',
          dataField: 'LastName',
          width: 120
      }, {
          text: 'Title',
          dataField: 'Title',
          width: 200
      }, {
          text: 'Birth Date',
          dataField: 'BirthDate',
          cellsFormat: 'd',
          width: 120
      }, {
          text: 'Hire Date',
          dataField: 'HireDate',
          cellsFormat: 'd',
          width: 120
      }, {
          text: 'Address',
          dataField: 'Address',
          width: 250
      }, {
          text: 'City',
          dataField: 'City',
          width: 120
      }, {
          text: 'Country',
          dataField: 'Country',
          width: 120
      }]

  });
  $('#treeGrid').on('rowBeginEdit', function (event) {
      var args = event.args;
      var row = args.row;
      alert("The row you are editing is: " + row.FirstName + " " + row.LastName);
  });
```

**html file**

```
<div id="treeGrid"></div>
```

Comment: i found the solution: used  the following code to checkbox property:checkboxes: function (rowKey, dataRow) {
                    var level = dataRow.level; 
                   if (level != 0) {
                     return true;
                   }
                   return false;
                },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, used the following code to checkbox property:

```
checkboxes: function (rowKey, dataRow) {
     var level = dataRow.level; 
     if (level != 0) {
      return true;
     }
     return false;
    }
```

Comment: @Kmeixner https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/documentation/jqxtreegrid/jqxtreegrid-api.htm Go there and look under checkboxes